# Facebook array into mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, facebook

I'm trying to build some data for each url that we have based on the total likes, shares etc so that I can a top ten list of which are the most liked and shared etc.

code isn't my fortie but this is what I have worked out but it seems to get the array but I can't seem to understand how I capture the array snippets and transpose them into a set table to hold the data.

```
$fql  = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";
$fql .= "total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM ";
$fql .= "link_stat WHERE url = 'http://www.google.com'";

$apifql="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql);
$json=file_get_contents($apifql);

$id = 311;

if(is_array($json)){
foreach($json as $key => $value){

$url = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['url'] );
$share_count = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['share_count'] );
$like_count = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['like_count'] );
$comment_count = mysql_real_escape_string( $value['comment_count'] )

$sql = "UPDATE `fb_counts` SET `url` = $url, `share_count` = $share_count, `like_count` = $like_count, `comment_count` = $comment_count WHERE id = $id" ;
mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
  }
}
```

Replaced the line with below and it shot out an error....

```
$json= json_decode(file_get_contents($apifql));
```

Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\FBCount.php on line 17

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\FBCount.php on line 47

I shorted the information requested to keep it more concise and the array is much shorter now, but still scratching my head. Array's really hurt my small head......lol

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [url] => http://www.munchkins.com/test-a-url-to-see-fb-result [share_count] => 56 [like_count] => 62 [comment_count] => 46 ) )

Ok starting to make a bit more sense.... managed to get an array to look like this....
                                                                                           Array ( [url] => http://www.google.com [share_count] => 5268340 [like_count] => 1342562 [comment_count] => 1716901 )

What I can't get my head around and I've spent hours trying to read how this works and I think I must be either too thick or the penny will drop soon... Is how to get the key => data into the db.

```
foreach ($fbdata2 as $key => $value) {

$url = mysql_real_escape_string($value[url]);    
$query = "UPDATE videos.fb_data SET 'url' = '$url' WHERE id='$id'";
mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_errno());
```

I've just selected the first key in the array to see if it works but I get it working and I've tried all manner of formats with no luck getting data I need into the db.

Really thanks for all your help - I'm an old timer so things aren't as easy for me to get my head around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use json_decode to transform json into PHP valiable.

```
$json= json_decode(file_get_contents($apifql));
```

You can also check this fragment of working code:

```
<?php
$fql  = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";
$fql .= "total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM ";
$fql .= "link_stat WHERE url = 'http://www.google.com'";
$apifql="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql);
$json= json_decode(file_get_contents($apifql), true);
foreach ( $json[0] as $key => $val ) {
   echo $key.' = '.$val."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, apologies had to edit the top posts as I don't have enough rep to reply to my own post... :-(

Comment: edited my original at the top with how far I've got so far - really close I feel just going bald trying to understand how arrays work...

Answer (score 0):

I used the **true** addon to help clean the array

```
$json= json_decode(file_get_contents($apifql),true);
```

Many Thanks for your help still took some brain scratching but tbh its not a bad thing as it helps me to understand things better. Being older my brain doesn't run at lig